# Python Constructing the left-hand coefficient matrix:

Tags: python

Constructing the left-hand coefficient matrix: Write a function which, when given
a list of chemical species and a list of elements, will return a 2-D array representing
the right-hand coefficient matrix A in either (3) or (7). Example: calling your func-tion with inputs of ['CO', 'H2O', 'CO2'] and ['C', 'H', 'O'] should return an
output of array([[1, 0, 1], [0, 2, 0], [1, 1, 2]]). Hint: column vectors c1,
c2, c3 and c4 can be assembled into a matrix with c [c1, c2, c3, c4] in SciPy.

so I'm thinking import scipy but I dont know how to start this...

Comment: You can do better than copy-pasting, can't you?

Comment: You copied the homework's description too literally (see, "func-tion", "(3) or (7)"). To import scipy you do `import scipy`, but I see no reason in using `scipy` for this. I'm nearly sure someone will post a complete answer to you, but I really hope that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't import any modules to solve this task. It's way too easy. But since this is such an elementary problem, i'll just give you some simple ideas you can use. From what i can understand the question is to return a two-dimentional list in which the number of each atom is represented in the appropriate index. Given this, the task is really just a matter of iterating over each character in each element, to see wether you have a match. Subsequently, check wether the next character is a digit using the isdigit() method.